# I'm getting a login prompt and warning when accessing my WSO2 Identity Server via Windows Authentication on Linux

Tags: linux, active-directory, wso2, windows-authentication, wso2-identity-server

I am in the process of evaluating WSO2 Identity server.

The current Intranet setup mixes between Linux and Windows devices. As Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) is a requirement in the SSO solution the company is going to implement, is there a way to get the Linux hosts to authenticate using IWA.

I have succeeded in using IWA from the windows terminals but when I log form Linux terminal I get a prompt.

The Linux terminals authenticate against Active Directory using Centrify DC Express. I have tried likewise-open also but I get the same result.

This is the warning I get when I log from Linux terminals:

```
WARN {waffle.apache.NegotiateAuthenticator} -  error logging in user: The     token supplied to the function is invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if the DNS reverse lookup record setup was correctly as this would be used to retrieve the service ticket for SSO.

On Linux host run: `nslookup <ipaddress of webserver>`

Then, verify if you have the SPN for HTTP service registered in AD with the reverse lookup record.

On Linux, if you are using Centrify Express please run:

```
adquery user -A <webserver samAccountName>
```

e.g.

```
adquery user -A webserver$
```

Or on AD, run:

```
setspn -L <webserver hostname>
```

You should see entry like:

> "HTTP/".

If the above have configured correctly, please check the klist output after the failure access:

e.g.

```
/usr/share/centrifydc/kerberos/bin/klist
```

And confirm if you see a HTTP service ticket exist.

e.g.

> ===
>
> 08/05/2015 19:44:07  08/06/2015 05:36:27 
>   HTTP/webserver.domain.local@DOMAIN.LOCAL  renew until 08/12/2015
>   19:36:27
>
> ===

If it does exist, this indicated that the webserver is not accepting the service ticket for some reason. Possibly the case sensitive of "HTTP" service or missing keytab entries in the keytab of your webserver etc. The problem seems to be on webserver side.

If it does not exist, this indicated that AD has denied your service ticket request. And a network trace on client side, would be able to tell what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I ran those commands but I didn't find the "HTTP/" entry. 

This is the output of klist
08/07/15 01:54:35  08/07/15 11:54:35  krbtgt/TEST.TESTACTIVEDIRECTORY@TEST.TESTACTIVEDIRECTORY
 renew until 08/14/15 01:54:24

Comment: What should I do in order to get the HTTP/ service ticket ?

Comment: Do you mean you are not able to locate the "HTTP" service through adquery or setspn command?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find the HTTP service. 
The IWA feature that WSO2 provides is based on NTLM. Can Centrify DC Express use NTLM ?